# body attribute in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

Do we have any body attribute the way we have in aura component, so we can just write the details in between component name tags.

```
<lwccmp> body details </lwccmp>.
```

we have body a default attribute in aura component, need this in lightning web component too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use unnamed slots.

```
<!-- lwccmp.html -->
<template>
    <div onprivateitemregister={handleChildRegister}>
        <!– Other markup here -->
        <slot><!-- Body details will be here.--></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

[More details about slots here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_best_composition)